# How to delete links except if it have a specific content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm deleting all the links of my file, but when the content is: "(VETADO)", I don't like to delete.

A piece of the webpage:

```
<a href="http://www.plan.com.br/ccivil_03.htm">(VETADO)</a>
<a href="http://www.plan.com.br/ccivil_04.htm">(Incluído em 2009).</a>
```

In this case, I'd like to keep the content of the first `a` and delete the second.

That's my code:

```
for tag in soup.findAll():
    if tag.name in ['a', 'strike']:
      tag.decompose()

allp = soup.findAll('p')
for p in allp:
    nonBreakSpace = u'\xa0'
    result = p.text.replace('\n', '').replace(nonBreakSpace, '')  
    print(result)
```

The result expected:

```
(VETADO)
```

Comment: Not fully understand your choice of the accepted answer as you've asked how to "delete the links" specifically and not return the desired one. But, I am happy as long as it helped you to solved the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry. You're right. I implemented what u said and works good. I did a little confuse to vote. Tku so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can basically do it in one go with a filter on the `text` attribute and [`.decompose()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose):

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: data = """<div>
             <a href="http://www.plan.com.br/ccivil_03.htm">(VETADO)</a>
             <a href="http://www.plan.com.br/ccivil_04.htm">(Incluído em 2009).</a>
             </div>"""

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

In [4]: for a in soup.find_all("a", text=lambda text: text and "VETADO" in text):
             a.decompose()   

In [4]: soup.prettify()
<div>
 <a href="http://www.plan.com.br/ccivil_04.htm">
  (Incluído em 2009).
 </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the HTML you have provided, you can try something like this perhaps:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmlStr = """
            <a href="http://www.plan.com.br/ccivil_03.htm">(VETADO)</a>
            <a href="http://www.plan.com.br/ccivil_04.htm">(Incluído em 2009).</a>
          """
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlStr, 'html.parser')

for i in range(len(soup.find_all('a'))):
    h = soup.find_all('a')[i].get_text()
    if('VETADO' in h):
        print(h)
```

Output:

```
(VETADO)
```

At this point, you know which indexes contain VETADO and you can add the necessary stuff to a list, or dataframe, or variable, or whatever you want.